# How to match HTML with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract some urls in an html file using python. Here is what the text look like:

```
preabc!precde<preefg<
```

I want to extract "cde" and "efg". The pattern I've used:

```
pre(.*?)<
pre(.(?!^pre)).*?<
```

However, none of them works:(. Note that real lengths of "cde" and "efg" are unknow. I'm not familier with regular expression so please explan your answers. Many thanks.

EDIT:

Sorry for my bad explanation and ambiguous example. I want to extract titles like "GIRL FRIENDS" **with certain date** (2014-7-31 in this case):

`<a href="http://rs.xidian.edu.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&amp;tid=662128&amp;extra=page%3D1" onclick="atarget(this)" class="s xst">GIRL  FRIENDS</a>
<span class="tps">&nbsp;...<a href="http://rs.xidian.edu.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=662128&amp;extra=page%3D1&amp;page=2">2</a></span>
<a href="http://rs.xidian.edu.cn/forum.php?mod=redirect&amp;tid=662128&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost" class="xi1">New</a>
</th>
<td class="by">
<cite>
<a href="http://rs.xidian.edu.cn/home.php?mod=space&amp;uid=265770" c="1">机器人</a></cite>
<em><span><span title="2014-7-31">昨天&nbsp;23:55</span></span></em>
</td>`

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you explain it rather than just downvote?

Comment: Is 'abc' length know? is the '<' and '!' present?

Comment: Yea, we're going to need to work off of

Comment: @hjpotter92 But it outputs "abc!precde" instead of "cde".

Comment: what makes "cde" and "efg" different from "pre" and "abc"? can you provide more examples of input + desired output?

Comment: btw, I hope you're not trying to parse HTML using regular expressions.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Do you want to extract "New" also or just "GIRL  FRIENDS"

Comment: @skamazin Just "GIRL FRIENDS". There're many titles in the same "pattern" in the html file.

Comment: @Wisatbff why don't you use an HTML parser, such as ``lxml.html``? You'll have a much more robust solution without having to get crazy with hyper-complex regexes..

Comment: What makes "GIRL  FRIENDS" from all the other titles? Telling us "There're many titles in the same "pattern"" is basically saying regex won't work for you at all

Comment: @skamazin The date below is supposed to be matched.

Comment: You need to use a parser for this. Look at BeautifulSoup or lxml

Comment: Ok. I'll try those tools later. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @Wisatbff Yea if you looking to do this for a very long file or for many files, I would go with a parser and not a regex. But if it's only this one instance, I can find a regex that'll work for you.

Comment: Alrighty, try my regex in my answer. Tell me if something goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
 (>([A-Z ]+?)<|title="([\d-]+))
```

[Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/gU6cE6/5)

The more specific and less predictable you get, the more complicated and unreadable the regex is going to be. I don't suggest using regex for this, instead try an HTML parser.

Comment: +1 the most frequently asked question gets the most frequent answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: Ok, forget it. You are right. I'll use a HTML parser instead. Thank you all:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is to not try and parse HTML with a regex. There are lots of html parsing libraries available. Using a regex is only going to cause headaches.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
pre.*!pre(.*)<pre(.*)<
```

Explanation:

`pre.*!` ignore the first part the 'abc' since it starts: start with `pre`, has a body of anycharacter in anylength(the `.*` part meets anything) ends with a `!`

`pre(.*)<` take the cde. Does the same as the above, but instead it stores whatever is in the body in the matching group 1, the `()` are matching groups.

`pre(.*)<` takes the efg. Same as above but stores in the matching group 2

Note that the `!` and both `<` are the ones responsible for dividing the string.

Comment: nope. [Beware ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)